# Join Broken Paragraphs HTMl Regex

Tags: epub, sigils

I'm trying to edit some `xhtml` on `Sigil`.

With the **command**

> < p>([a-z])

I'm able to find all paragraphs that begin with *lower case*. That tells me that they shouldn't be separate from the previous one. It's just a conversion issue.

What should I do to delete both the `< p>` from that paragraph and the `< /p>` from the previous one in order to join the two blocks of text into **one single paragraph**?

It looks something like this:

> < p>  ... that is why relationships< /p>

`< p>` are **not** what they should be.

And it should be:

> < p> that is why relationships are not what they should be.< /p>

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about Sigil, but the following regex should be able to do that:

First find:

```
</p>\s*<p>(\s*[a-z])
```

The replace it with:

```
$1
```

What this means:

\s* : Any amount of whitespace

$1 : The group () youll keep after replacing

Answer (score 0):

Or an easiest way by checking *Dot Matches All*:

```
<p>(.+?)</p>
```

And then you Replace only with: `$1` or `/1` (*Group*)

It will remain only the block of text.

`(.+?)` - Everything until the first *entity* like **slashes** or **>** etc.

`(.*?)` - Everything including *entities*. (**Careful!**)

Build your `regex`:

- if you have newlines use `\n`
- if you have space use `\s`
- if you want to exclude something use `^`
- if you want to use both `\n` and `\s` go `(\n\s)`
- if you want ANY of that use `*` after it. Ex: `\s*` (*any white space
  until first entity*)
- if you want to search by first letter go `([a-z])` or all letters `([a-z]+)`
- by numbers `([0-9])` or more numbers `([0-9]+)`
- only 2 first letters `([a-z]{2})` etc.

  **Advices**:
- Always ***USE*** *preview* or *replace only the first match* to see the difference.
- Use them into groups with brackets `()`

Hope this helps you understand better your issue.